# Android Renderscript Allocation.USAGE_SHARED crash

Tags: android, allocation, bitmapdata, renderscript

I am getting a crash while running my app which uses renderscript. Unfortunately, the logcat does not give any specific details.

```
b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ib.getWidth(), ib.getHeight(),ib.getConfig());

Allocation mInAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, inBitmap,
                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);

Allocation mOutAllocation2 = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS,
                 outBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                 Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
```

...execute an algorithm from .rs file and later do the below

```
mOutAllocation2.copyTo(outBitmap)`;
```

The same code sequence runs perfectly fine, when I used USAGE_SCRIPT flag instead of USAGE_SHARED for mOutAllocation2.

Any help on why this could happen?

I read in android docs that if the allocation is of the type USAGE_SHARED, then the copy operation from allocation to the bitmap (see above) is faster. 
Currently, I am seeing copies from allocation to bitmaps running into secs for decently large images (8MP and above)

I am using Nexus 10 (Android 4.3) currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to be using Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT | Allocation.USAGE_SHARED. createFromBitmap(RenderScript, Bitmap) will set that for you when possible.

Second, if your copy times are taking that long, you're probably seeing script execution as well. Script execution is asynchronous, so the wall clock time of copyTo(Bitmap) may include significantly more than just the copy.

Comment: After further debug, the crash happens at mOutAllocation2.Syncall(Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT), which was called before mOutAllocation2.copyTo(Bitmap). In my application, the allocation is not shared really between multiple kernels. So using USAGE_SHARED flag for the allocation does not make sense. However, I wasn't expecting a crash for an incorrect usage.

Comment: your second point on wallclock time measurement of copyTo(Bitmap) makes sense. However, I do call syncAll(Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT) before copyTo(Bitmap). Shouldn't Allocation.syncall ensure all the asynchronous operations on the allocation are completed?

Comment: syncAll is a little more complicated than that. the call you're looking for is RenderScript.finish(), not syncAll.

Comment: RenderScript.finish() works. Timing measurements are now consistent and meaningful. I see that my algorithm implementation is consuming time and not the copyTo(Bitmap) function

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and I resolved it, this issue was happening because my bitmap configuration was not Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, we should convert it to ARGB_8888 before applying the blur.

```
    Bitmap U8_4Bitmap;
    if (yourBitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) {
        U8_4Bitmap = yourBitmap;
    } else {
        U8_4Bitmap = yourBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }
```